# Is there a grammar for this language? $w^{m-1}aca^m$?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I have to form a free context grammar for this language $w^{m-1}aca^m$ where $w \in \{a,b\}$, so what I have been able to do is this:

$X \rightarrow SacA$
$S \rightarrow aS|bS$
$A \rightarrow aA$

But I don't know how to do it or if possible, condition the exponents as long as $ S $ is repeated $ m-1 $ times, and $ A $, $ m $ times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attack it from the exact wrong side.

First, the language is the same as $\{w^m aca a^m|w\in\{a,b\},m\in\mathbb{N}\}$. For this, you apply a rule that adds $w$ on the left and $a$ on the right repeatedly, and then inserts $aca$ in the middle and is done. By using one rule that adds both on the left and the right side, you make the number of w's and a's the same.

$S \rightarrow WSa$
$S \rightarrow aca$
$W \rightarrow a|b$

That’s it.

Comment: @JohanC yes, it will work

Answer (score 0):

If the question is really about $w \in \{ a, b \}$ (i.e., $w$ is an $a$ or a $b$), a grammar would be:

$\begin{align*}
   S &\to a A a \mid b B a \\
   A &\to a A a \mid a c a \\
   B &\to b B a \mid a c a
\end{align*}$